# zend framework 2 configuring module with dependency injection fails

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm trying to configure the application module with dependency injection. But the dependencies seem not to be injected. Here is the part of my config:

```
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver' => array(
                'injections' => array(
                        'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver',
                        'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack',
                ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                        'map'  => array(
                                'home'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/home.phtml',
                                'site/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/site/layout.phtml',
                                'site/error'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/site/error.phtml',
                                'site/404'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/site/404.phtml',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                        'paths'  => array(
                                'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                        'resolver' => 'Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver',
                ),
        ),
        'Zend\Mvc\View\DefaultRenderingStrategy' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                        'layoutTemplate' => 'site/layout',
                ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\View' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                        'renderer'=>'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer'
                    )
        ),
    )
```

),

The `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` object is not injected. How can configure my app to use DI for Views and Resolvers?

Comment: Are you on the latest release of ZF2? I think most of this is now done automatically if you take a look at the Skeleton app in the Application module's module.config.php.

Comment: I´ve thought so too. But the access the dependecies only with the DipendecyInjector that is configured in the config file of module